# Extract host and suffix from URL

Tags: twig

Without using an extension how can I provide a URL and get its host and suffix in Twig? It looks like I need an extension to use parse_url but I'm hoping Twig has an inbuilt function to handle this.

Something similar to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php would be great.

Comment: Any reason not to use an extesion then? You could always chain the function without using an extension by doing `$twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('parse_url', 'parse_url'));`

Comment: No, it doesn't have such [function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/index.html) built it.